# array_rand with seed

Tags: php, arrays, random, seed

I have multiple image file names in an array and would like to generate random image that are fixed for a whole day, so I would like to use a fixed seed for the same day using date("Ymd") and this seed will change daily, thus generating new unique seed every day.

Problem is that array_rand doesn't accept seed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the same seed will not guarantee that you will get the same number every time. I would create some pseudo-random function, for example dependent from year, month and day, but not hours, minutes, seconds, that will give the same result only from these values, for example

```
function pseudorandom_day_image_index($array_of_pictures){
   $year=date('Y');
   $month=date('m');
   $day=date('d');
   return ($year*$month*$day) % count($array_of_pictures);
}
```

This will give you constant (for a day) index of a picture

Comment: i edited the question, since it wasn't clear. array_rand doesn't accept seed as an input.

Comment: You don't need to get random array but one picture. I reedited answer and the function gives this index. G_G is also good idea, because its math basis is the same.

Comment: WARNING! your code has a serious bug! if the number of images (the length of the array) is grater of a given $year*$month*$day (it could be the case!) your code will end up selecting only a small part of the images.

Comment: @G_G That's why I use a modulo (`%` operator). In fact our solutions are equal at the idea :)

Comment: you can even multiple the by by a number between 1 and 2744 for a larger seed. note that you can't go higher since modules % is limited only to int length values

Answer (score 3):

compute the hash of the human readable string returned by date("Ymd"), you'll get an unique seed for every day

something like:

```
$seed = md5(date("Ymd"));
```

Init yout rand function with your day-seed:

```
srand((int)$seed);
```

your new array index will be:

```
$random_array_index = $rand() % $array_size;
```

Comment: thank you for the tip, but the problem is that array_rand doesnt accept a seed input. how should i do it?

Comment: where is the problem? let's compute you array index with another PRNG function! ;) $array_index = rand() % $arraysize; have a look at my answer, I've just edited it

Comment: remember srand takes long number and hash contain characters

Comment: dude, md5 returns characters. seed can only accept numbers. try your code before posting. thanks